# A bit field as parameter and as return of the function

Tags: c, bit-fields

I have the following type:

```
My_Union_t Data;
typedef union My_Union {
byte Byte;
 struct {
    byte b0:1;
    byte b1:1;                                       
    byte b2:1;
    byte b3:1;
    byte b4:1;
    byte b5:1;
    byte b6:1;
    byte b7:1;
 } Bits;
} My_Union_t;
```

Because, the bit field has no address, I created a function that takes it and returns it.

Is it the best method to pass  a bit field as a parameter ?

```
Bits Invert(Bits Bit)
{
 return (~Bits)
}

void Function(void)
{    
 Data.Bits.b1 = Invert(Data.Bits.b1);     
}
```

Comment: Bit's address is an address of byte plus bit index. Or, if you pass byte by value, just bit index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot apply `~` operator to the entire `struct Bits`, only to its individual parts. Changing the data type to `byte` will fix this problem:

```
byte Invert(byte bit) {
    return (~bit);
}
```

This will compile and work ([demo](http://ideone.com/X3UrAi)). The compiler will supply all the "magic" to make the appropriate bit manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

The details of how arguments are passed and returned are largely dependent on the compiler. Arguments will be passed in a natural type, such as an int. Bitfields are not a natural types and their implementation is compiler dependent.

Parameters are passed to functions by pushing the paramters onto the stack. The return value is returned in a register. When pushing values onto the stack, the compiler takes care to keep the stack aligned, which means it will push in 32 bit chunks on a 32 bit machine, and 64 bit chucks on a 64 bit machine.

Even a byte will not be passed as a byte on most systems, it will be passed as an int.

(An alternative is to use native types and do the bit operations yourself.)